# Netplan error, error on nameserver

Tags: networking, server, 17.10, netplan

I'm trying to setup a Ubuntu server and running in to a problem setting up a static IP.

My OS is as below:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:        17.10
Codename:       artful
```

My 01-netcfg.yaml is below:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0f0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.109/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        adresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

When running `sudo netplan apply` I get the below error. Same error when running `debug`.

> Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 8: unknown key adresses

All my google attempts for a correct .yaml file says this should work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NetworkManager` instead of `networkd` may be more appropriate. See [Configuration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan#Configuration) in the Netplan wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is telling you that it doesn't understand *adresses*. Please try:

```
addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Any improvement?

Comment: That worked!
That was just plain stupid of me, was blindly checking on "nameservers:" since the error said it was that line that was wrong :D

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This is a netplan joke. You must read your error message

> Error in network definition //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 9 column 8: unknown key adresses

as "there is a section on **line 9** (here **nameservers**) and in this section (in some line below, but surely not the line 9) is a keyword (**key**) **adresses** which is **unknown**.

And now the message is clear and the solution is straightforward.