# Netplan complains "unknown key bridges"

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I'm trying to set up a network bridge for KVM but I keep getting a the error

> Error in network definition `//etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 5 column 0: unknown key bridges.`

The funny thing is, line 5 column 0 is `network`, not `bridges`, so I'm not sure why it is saying bridges. Here is the `.yaml` I'm trying:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
```

Comment: Yaml files are very picky about correct indentation. Place two spacebars before the bridges keyword and the error message should go away.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks for the help, and so promptly too.

Comment: please post the solution solved your question as an answer below in "Your Answer" part:  )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yaml files are very picky about correct indentation. Place two spacebars before the bridges keyword and the error message should go away.

Answer (score 2):

The bridges should be the same level with the version, not the network

Comment: This is the same suggestion as the accepted answer from three years ago 

Answer (score 0):

This would be rather a comment but missing reputation.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1076559/873039

This error message is saying you have a problem in a section which is defined on **line 5 column 0** (**network** section), and within this section somewhere is a keyword **bridges** which is a problem.

It looks like these netplan error messages are very messy and unclear, even right in their logic. Here it says the keyword is unknown however it only has bad indentation.